# ninject - inject dependency to existing object during request

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control

Ninject creates for me instance of class A that depends on class B (so ninject created also object B). Ninject is configured to return single instance of class A (InSingletonScope) and many instances of class B (InTrancientScope).
Class A has property that allows to get/set dependency of object B.

Is it possible to retrieve instance of class A with newly created instance B every time I request for the same instance of class A?

The method OnActivation would do the trick if it was executed on every request, not only first time.

Or maybe this is some anti-pattern that I am going to do?

**EDIT:**
To avoid XY problem I will try to explain more details. The solution is too big to explain everything so long story short:

There is an **Operation** to do, for example stocktaking. The operation is filled by three **Presenters** (P1, P2, P3). Presenters manages corresponding **Views** (V1, V2, V3). User inputs data in views, presenters gets the data from views and saves to Operation.
All presenters and views are singletons (InSingletonScope) to avoid creation objects every time it is needed. Views are injected into appropriate presenters.
Every time operation starts there should be created new instance of operation and injected to all presenters that already exist.

Comment: you probably instead of injecting the dependency into the singleton. Inject a factory for that dependency into the singleton, and call create on that factory everytime you want an instance

Comment: you can always inject in the service locator to resolve the dependency every time you want.

Comment: OK, that is a solution, but I wonder if there is simpler solution. Some .OnResolved method would be very simple. I wonder why there is no such thing.

Comment: To be honest, it is a pretty simple solution ;)

Comment: Injecting factory is not applicable, because actually there are a few classes(A1, A2, A3....) with B dependency. The B object is used across some scope in all this classes. After exiting from a scope and entering again there should be created a new instance of B. And isn't service locator considered as anti-pattern?

Comment: What is A1, A2, A3 and B. You can use the DI scopes, it's hard to help you solve a problem where you haven't given the real scenario, this is starting to sound like a XY problem....

Comment: I have put some edit with explanation.

Comment: I don't see how a factory doesn't solve this, the if you are dealing with state across 3 classes which needs to be "coordinated" then you can have the factory store this data in memory and wait for the user to kick off the process - at which point a new instance of operation is created, all the data is fed to it. I would be very careful with having state shared across so many views, I would always try and limit state as much as possible. Also don't try and premature optimise things, you shouldn't really be worrying about singletons and transients that much for performance...

Comment: Thank you for help. I solved the problem with factory. The performance is important because program works on Windows Embedded on device with slow hardware.

Comment: Can you add some sample code?

Comment: Don't use Ninject if you want speed then, use something like LightInject

Comment: Does it work under .net Compact Framework? As I see it does not. I tried another IOC (OpenNETCF.IoC) which is much faster (based on test http://blog.opennetcf.com/2011/04/29/benchmarking-opennetcfs-ioc-framework/) but it has bugs and requires using attributes. So I decided to use ninject because it is well tested and very flexible and also works on many platforms - so this knowledge will pay off.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you request the Presenter from the IOC it returns the same presenter with the same Operation Factory. The Operation Factory can return the same object or new object if you set IsValid to false.
The sample code that is created to solve the problem:

**THE OPERATION:**

```
public abstract class Operation
    {
        protected Logger logger;

        public Operation(Logger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
    }


public class StocktakingOperation : Operation
    {
        public string test = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        public StocktakingOperation(Logger logger)
            : base(logger)
        {

        }
    }
```

**THE FACTORY:**

```
class OperationFactory<T> where T : Operation
    {
        private Func<T> ObjectCreation;

        private T ValidObject;


        public OperationFactory(Func<T> ObjectCreation)
        {
            IsValid = false;
            this.ObjectCreation = ObjectCreation;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// While is True then the same operation is returned.
        /// Set it to False to invalidate current operation so the next call to get operation will return new operation.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }



        public T GetOperation()
        {
            if (IsValid == false)
            {
                ValidObject = ObjectCreation();
                IsValid = true;
            }

            return ValidObject;
        }

    }


class StocktakingOperationFactory : OperationFactory<StocktakingOperation>
    {
        public StocktakingOperationFactory(Func<StocktakingOperation> ObjectCreation)
            : base(ObjectCreation)
        {

        }
    }
```

**PRESENTER**

```
class StocktakingPresenter : BaseOperationPresenter<StocktakingPresentersManager, OPERATION_TYPE>
    {

        public StocktakingPresenter(QuickForm QuickForm, StocktakingOperationFactory OperationFactory, VIEW_TYPE view, Workspace workspace, Logger logger)
            : base(QuickForm, OperationFactory, view, workspace, logger)
        {}


    }
```

**AND IOC:**

```
kernel.Bind<StocktakingOperation>().ToSelf();

kernel.Bind<StocktakingOperationFactory>().ToMethod(c =>
            new StocktakingOperationFactory(() => { return kernel.Get<StocktakingOperation>(); })
            ).InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<StocktakingPresenter>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```